# Sequelize DataTypes not being validated

Tags: node.js, validation, types, sequelize.js

I've been learning Node.JS as of recently, and I'm currently using Sequelize.
I have a problem with the update method; it updates just fine, but when I input values that should be incompatible with an attribute's datatype, it still passes it, and updates it in the database.

For exemple: in Postman, when I try to update a record's "completed" attribute with a string, it gets updated even though the datatype was specified as a Boolean, and delivers no error message(request status is 200).
Here is the code:

- todo model:

  ```
  module.exports = function (sequelInst, DataTypes){
    return sequelInst.define('todo', {
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          len: [1, 250]
        }
      },
      completed: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false
      }
    });
  };
  ```
- server.js:

  ```
      ...

      app.put('/todos/:id', function(req,res){
        var body =_.pick(req.body, 'description', 'completed');
        var attributes = {};
        var paramId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

        if( body.hasOwnProperty('completed')){
          attributes.completed = body.completed;
        }

        if( body.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
          attributes.description = body.description;
        }

        db.todo.findById(paramId)
        .then(function(todo){ // First Promise Chain
          if(todo){
            return todo.update(attributes);
          }
          else{
            res.status(404).send("No todo corresponding to id");
          }
        }, function () {
          res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        })
        .then(function(todo) { // Second Promise Chain
          res.send(todo);
        }, function (e){
          res.status(400).json(e);
        });

      });
  ```

Answer (score 3):

[Instance.update](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#updating-saving-persisting-an-instance) does not validate based on type.

Since you are not getting an error, your probably using SQLite or another storage which does not have strict validation on types at the database level either.

You need to add your own validator. If you do it like this:

```
completed: {
  type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  allowNull: false,
  defaultValue: false,
  validate: {
    isBoolean: true
  }
}
```

You will get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: Validation isBoolean failed
```

However it looks like this validation is deprecated:

```
validator *deprecated* you tried to validate a boolean but this library (validator.js) validates strings only. Please update your code as this will be an error soon. node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:276:33
```

This will work:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

validate: {
  isBoolean: function (val) {
    if (!_.isBoolean(val)) {
      throw new Error('Not boolean.');
    }
  }
}
```

Will give you an error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: Not boolean.
```